# How should I feed my Kinsect for each gameplay style?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

I don't know which Nectar to use on my Kinsect according to the gameplay style I want to have.

I know that each stat, **Power**, **Speed** and **Stamina** (and their combinations), apply for a different kind of gameplay but I'm not sure which does what. There's also the **Elemental damage** to take into account.

**So for which gameplay style should I improve each stat?**

I don't ask for the best build to kill monsters the most effectively at the highest level, but which build correspond to which gameplay, to choose the funniest to me, optimization apart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Speed** affects how fast your kinsect moves, **power** affects how much damage it does, and **stamina** affects how far it can go before it needs to return.

If you're just playing through the game, most people suggest that you just upgrade your kinsect's speed, since that's probably the most important stat as it allows you to gather the different extracts much more easily. Stamina is also pretty helpful. Once you get to the end of G-rank and can make rarity 9 or 10 weapons, however, this strategy becomes less effective, and at this point it's suggested that you make a new insect glaive from scratch, as there's no way to "reset" its kinsect.

As you upgrade your kinsect, you will notice that it gets different abilities depending on what you feed it, such as *Ext Effic (S)*. If you upgrade your kinsect in certain ways, you will eventually be able to get one of four "final" kinsect types:

- **Stored Extract +1:** Your kinsect gets the ability to hold two extracts at once
- **Pierce Up:** Your kinsect will never bounce off of the monster (similar to the hunter ability Mind's Eye)
- **Charge Time:** If you hold down X+R, your kinsect will "charge", and when you release it, it will fly off faster and farther. This greatly reduces the time it takes to fully charge your kinsect
- **Extract Extender:** Extract buffs gained from the kinsect will last twice as long, including the red+orange+white buff

The vast majority of insect glaive players I see online use the Extract Extender bug. It's the best simply because you don't have to go gather extracts nearly as frequently as you would otherwise, meaning you can spend more time attacking the monster!

Charge Time is also worth a mention, especially the Blunt one, called Fleetflammer, as it has a pretty high motion value when fully charged *and* deals decent KO damage. If you like attacking with your bug a lot, this is the bug you want.

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6MzM2CqDO-E) is a pretty good guide on how to upgrade your kinsect, and what the different numbers mean and which extracts to use, although it's for the Extract Extender kinsect and not the Charge Time one. It shouldn't be very difficult to figure out how to apply it to the Charge Time bug, though.

[image: Kinsect upgrade flowchart]

Finally, don't bother with element on kinsects. It doesn't increase their damage by much, and its only use is just giving your kinsect a special particle effect when it hits the monster or changing a small part of its color. (Fire kinsects get red, thunder ones get orange, etc)

Comment: m'kay, that chart is pretty cool.

Comment: Actually, elemental damage on a kinsect are THE MOST POWERFUL source of elemental damage.  There is a very long thread on GameFaqs with all the testing details.

Comment: @Nelson: Got a link? My worry is that if you pump your kinsect full of elemental nectar then it won't have enough growth left to be able to reach one of the four final types. I'd think the abilities you could get from the final kinsects would outweigh the elemental damage.

Comment: You go for the final form and use the rest for element. It's the kinsect sticky on the mh4u forum on gamefaqs.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer :

- **Power** is the damage your Kinsect does on impact
- **Speed** is the Kinsect's flight speed
- **Stamina** is the number of times you can tell it to attack before it has to back to your arm

And yeah, there is elemental damage too. Pretty much self-explanatory.

---

However, you shouldn't just level those stats blindly. The Kinsects evolve to gain useful skills, and their evolution is governed by their stats ; you should decide what final form you want it to take, and plan accordingly.

Here is a link to [a nice guide](http://gaijinhunter.tumblr.com/post/101073637097/mh4g-guide-to-the-new-rare-kinsects-glaive) which explains really well the differences between Kinsects and how to obtain them.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, what I'd like to know is that, for example, the **Power+Speed** gives the bonus **Pierce Power Up** which is apparently useful to cut tails or KO monsters, so if I want to use my Kinsect to cut tails I should make a **Power+Speed** Kinsect? If I make a **Power+Stamina** Kinsect, should I focus on attacking with my Insect more than hitting the monster myself? Or is it totally unrelated (but then what's the point of choosing which path I want)? You tell me which stat does what but that doesn't really tell me how I should play accordingly of the stats I upgrade.

Comment: Generally, the consensus is that the best kinsect overall is the "Extract Effect Extender" one, since it makes your extract buffs last twice as long, meaning you spend more time attacking and less time using the bug. On top of that you'll want to maximize its speed, since that makes getting extracts a lot easier. The guide that @Ealhad linked is quite outdated though -- googling for "kinsect upgrade guide" should give you plenty of good walkthroughs on how to build the perfect kinsect. If you're just going through the game though, dump everything in speed/stam.

Comment: @Pyritie The link may be old (and with japanese name), it is still the clearest I could find.

Comment: @Ananas Your interpretation is correct. Some effects are good if you want to focus on attacking with your Kinsect, other aim to make him buff you more.

Comment: @Ealhad I posted an answer with more information on the four final kinsect types, let me know what you think